# I have a question about routing in React Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've done a static export with React Next.js 13 and am serving it with Nginx. I've already set up the location configuration in Nginx. Can you guide me on how to ensure that when I manually enter the URL for the /signup page, I'm not redirected to the main page?

### Directory tree

```
/src/app
├ [DIR] signup
└─ page.tsx (signup page)
└ page.tsx (main page)
```

### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

### next.config.js

```js
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
    images: { unoptimized: true },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

### /src/app/page.tsx

```js
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>main page</div>
  )
}
```

### /src/app/signup/page.tsx

```js
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>signup page</div>
  )
}
```

### nginx

```bash
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: Could you share more info. Basically you should not be redirected to main page anyway. That's how NextJS works. Are you being automatically redirected from /signup to main page right now?